# Implementing a debounced buffer with RxSwift, is this correct?

Tags: swift, rx-swift, reactivex

I am relatively new to **RxSwift**, but I am looking forward to using it more in my projects and I would love to hear some feedback on an operator I just wrote.

The functionality I am missing is a debounced buffer: A buffer that behaves exactly like the `debounce` operator, but instead of emitting only the latest value it should emit all collected values since the last emission.

In **RxJava** this is easily achievable by using a buffer with another observable as a "closing selector":

```
// From: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Backpressure
//
// we have to multicast the original bursty Observable so we can use it
// both as our source and as the source for our buffer closing selector:
Observable<Integer> burstyMulticast = bursty.publish().refCount();
// burstyDebounced will be our buffer closing selector:
Observable<Integer> burstyDebounced = burstMulticast.debounce(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
// and this, finally, is the Observable of buffers we're interested in:
Observable<List<Integer>> burstyBuffered = burstyMulticast.buffer(burstyDebounced);
```

In **RxSwift** though this version of the buffer operator doesn't exist (I think this issue is related: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/590), so I tried to solve the issue myself.

---

My first approach was just building the debounced buffer:

```
extension ObservableType {
    func debouncedBuffer(_ dueTime: RxTimeInterval, scheduler: SchedulerType) -> Observable<[E]> {
        var valueBuffer: [E] = []

        let observable = self.do(onNext: { (value) in
            valueBuffer.append(value)
        }, onError: { (error) in
            valueBuffer = []
        }, onCompleted: {
            valueBuffer = []
        }, onSubscribe: {
            valueBuffer = []
        }, onDispose: {
            valueBuffer = []
        }).debounce(dueTime, scheduler: scheduler).flatMap { (value) -> Observable<[E]> in
            let emitValues = valueBuffer
            valueBuffer = []
            return Observable<[E]>.just(emitValues)
        }

        return observable
    }
}
```

---

My second approach was building the buffer which any closing condition (like the RxJava version):

```
extension ObservableType {
    func buffer<R>(_ selector: Observable<R>) -> Observable<[E]> {
        var valueBuffer: [E] = []

        return Observable.create { observer in
            let selectorSubscription = selector.subscribe(onNext: { (value) in
                let emitValues = valueBuffer
                valueBuffer = []
                observer.on(.next(emitValues))
            }, onError: { (error) in
                valueBuffer = []
                observer.on(.error(error))
            }, onCompleted: {
                valueBuffer = []
                observer.on(.completed)
            }, onDisposed: {
                valueBuffer = []
            })

            let subscription = self.subscribe(onNext: { (value) in
                valueBuffer.append(value)
            }, onError: { (error) in
                observer.on(.error(error))
                selectorSubscription.dispose()
            }, onCompleted: {
                observer.on(.completed)
                selectorSubscription.dispose()
            }, onDisposed: {
                observer.on(.completed)
                selectorSubscription.dispose()
            })
            return subscription
        }
    }
}
```

---

I have tested these two operators and they seem to work, also tested handling different combinations of onError, onDispose, and onCompleted events.

But I would still love to hear some feedback from more experienced people if this is at least an acceptable solution without leaks, and if I am violating any RX contracts.

I also created a pasterbin with some test code: http://pastebin.com/1iAbUPf8

Comment: I would suggest you propose a PR on [RxSwiftExt](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxSwiftExt) and also check out the [RxSwift Slack channel](http://rxswift-slack.herokuapp.com/).

Comment: Thanks, slack channel is a good idea, and I'll think about creating PR.

Answer (score 1):

Here is mine for `buffer(bufferOpenings, bufferClosingSelector)`. It may require further review.

```
extension ObservableType {

    func buffer<R>(bufferOpenings: Observable<R>, bufferClosingSelector: (R)->Observable<R>) -> Observable<[E]> {
        var valueBuffer: [E]? = nil

        let operatorObservable = Observable<[E]>.create({ observer in
            let subject = PublishSubject<[E]>()

            let closingsSub = bufferOpenings
                .doOnNext({ _ in
                    valueBuffer = []
                })
                .flatMap({ opening in
                    return bufferClosingSelector(opening)
                })
                .subscribeNext({ _ in
                    if let vb = valueBuffer {
                        subject.onNext(vb)
                    }
                    valueBuffer = nil
                }
            )

            let bufferSub = self.subscribe(
                onNext: { value in
                    valueBuffer?.append(value)
                },
                onError: { error in
                    subject.onError(error)
                },
                onCompleted: {
                    subject.onCompleted()
                },
                onDisposed: {
                }
            )

            let subjectSub = subject.subscribe(
                onNext: { (value) in
                    observer.onNext(value)
                },
                onError: { (error) in
                    observer.onError(error)
                },
                onCompleted: {
                    observer.onCompleted()
                },
                onDisposed: {
                }
            )

            let combinedDisposable = CompositeDisposable()

            combinedDisposable.addDisposable(closingsSub)
            combinedDisposable.addDisposable(bufferSub)
            combinedDisposable.addDisposable(subjectSub)

            return combinedDisposable

        })

        return operatorObservable
    }

}
```